# Unable to send an email at hotmail from CRM

Tags: php, email, outlook, phpmailer

We unable send an email from CRM at hotmail. We use google app as email host. Our custom applications PHP by our own developer. We able send email at every domain like yahoo, AOL and other domain except hotmail account.

We checked our PHPMailer script and also run google smtm but nothing is working. Please help me out of this issue.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHPMailer - Mail() basic test</title>
</head>
<body>`enter code here`
<?php
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
//$mail->IsHTML(true);
//$mail->CharSet = 'windows-1251';
$body             = 'This is ....';
$mail->AddReplyTo("task@mytasker.com","Mytasker1");
//$mail->SetFrom('deep_m@outlook.com', 'Deep');
//$mail->SetFrom('saikat_mytasker@hotmail.com', "Saikat Mallick");
$mail->SetFrom("task@mytasker.com","Mytasker");
$address = "saikat@mytasker.com";
//$mail->AddAddress('saikat_mytasker@hotmail.com', "Saikat Mallick");
$mail->AddAddress('deep_m@outlook.com', 'Deep');
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Saikat Mallick");
$mail->Subject    = "Mytasker 123 ...";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example and are using an old version of PHPMailer. Please [update](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably hotmail servers are classifying your email content or servers as spam and is auto blocked. Though this is a little off topic  but may i suggest to switch to third party email senders such as [mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) or [mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/). In this way, you will mitigate the risk of your content / servers being classified / marked as spam and ensure 99.99% hitting inbox rate